# Clone/copy an array and modify it without affecting the source array?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

So let's say I have an array like this:

```
string[] words = new string[3];
words[0] = "welcome";
words[1] = "hello";
words[2] = "hey";
```

and I want to clone/copy it and will modify it:

```
string[] new_words = words;
new_words[1] = "hi!";
```

The problem is that it actually changes the `words[1] = "hello";` to `words[1] = "hi!";` as well which is not what I wanted to do.
How can I copy/clone an array and modify it without affecting its source? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone should work:

```
var newWords=(string[])words.Clone();
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I do that I cannot access it anymore? `newWords[0]...` it will say `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: After casting to `string[]` this isn't just an `object` anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your cloning logic in a method.

`void Swap(string[] arr) => arr[0] = "Temp";`

Comment: Thank you! But can you give me context to what that code does? (I'm not really familiar with it).